# iDanero.us swiper - initial div width is incorrect when loading data dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, swiper.js

I am starting a web application using the Swiper framework.
I have started using the simple demo-app provided within the library.
When I replace the content of the demo app with a dynamic content using JSON from Ajax call, I find that the initial 'swiper-wrapper' class width is 0px until I change the browser size and then it generates the correct width.

This is my Jquery code for loading the data and I located it before the  tag. 
I tried different locations for the code as well.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "JSON",
          url: "json.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
          success: function(data) {
            var toadd;
            toadd = '';
            for (var i=0; i < data.length;i++)
            {           
                toadd+='<div class="swiper-slide"><div class="swiper-container scroll-container"><div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div><div class="swiper-wrapper"><div class="swiper-slide"><div class="page-inner">';
                toadd+="<h1>" + data[0]["title"] + "</h1>";
                toadd+="<img class=\"movie-pic\" src="+data[0]["image"]+">";
                toadd+="<div class=\"movie-text\">Test language</div>";
                toadd+="</div></div></div></div></div>";    
            }
            $(".swiper-wrapper").html( toadd );
          }
        });
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: When are you initializing Swiper? If its on document.ready then you need to initialize after appending the html

Comment: It's done inside the simple-app.js file located after my JS function

Comment: ok then in the success method try `mySwiper.resizeFix() or mySwiper.reInit() ` where mySwiper will be the variable you have in your js. [See docs for usage](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/api.php)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong buddy. I found the same problem when i was new to it but later on i came to know that i have to generate html according to its syntax. [swiper](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/api.php) syntax of html is as follow :

```
<div class="swiper-container">  \\ This is main container of your swiper
<div class="swiper-wrapper">    \\ wrapper is immediate child of container and than you have slides inside it
  <!--First Slide-->
  <div class="swiper-slide"> 
    <!-- Any HTML content of the first slide goes here -->
  </div>

  <!--Second Slide-->
  <div class="swiper-slide">
    <!-- Any HTML content of the second slide goes here -->
  </div>

  <!--Third Slide-->
  <div class="swiper-slide"> 
    <!-- Any HTML content of the third slide goes here -->
  </div>
  <!--Etc..-->
  </div>
  </div>
```

where as you are taking slide as an outer div and inside slide you are adding swiper-container and wrapper which is totally wrong. Your for loop syntax will be as follow :

```
 var toadd;
 toadd = '<div class="swiper-container"><div class="swiper-wrapper">';
 for (var i=0; i < data.length;i++)
 {

      toadd+='<div class="swiper-slide"><div class="page-inner">';
      toadd+="<h1>" + data[0]["title"] + "</h1>";
      toadd+="<img class=\"movie-pic\" src="+data[0]["image"]+">";
      toadd+="<div class=\"movie-text\">Test language</div>";
      toadd+="</div></div>";

 }
 toadd+='</div></div>'
 $("parent_ctrl_swiper_id").html( toadd );
```

Comment: I tried what you adviced. Unfortunately it does not work. I think the structure is not correct in this specific case. Please have a look on the demo-apps/simple folder. This is the html structure they have: <div class="swiper-pages swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
   <div class="swiper-slide">
    <div class="swiper-container scroll-container">
     <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
     <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
       <div class="page-inner"> </div></div></div></div></div>

Comment: than have you initialized your swiper after adding html to document?

Comment: I tried moving the src="js/simple-app.js" after my JS script... That did not work as well

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by adding the following function after initialize.

```
function reinitSwiper(swiper) {
  setTimeout(function () {
   swiper.reInit();
  }, 500);
}
```

Thanks for the help